# Integrate skype for business in uwp app

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have been trying to find the best way to integrate skype for business in my uwp app. However, there are a ton of articles in MSDN and Skype/Office 365 developer pages. Most of them are from many months ago.

What I want to do is simply place a skype call OR skype chat from within my uwp app. I would prefer to integrate it fully into my app but I am also okay if it just launches the skype for business app.

However, I am not seeing any way to do this. Am I missing something or did MS leave skype for business out of uwp integration?

Here is what I read so far:

1. The skype for business sdk. This looks perfect! But, it is only for Android and ios?
2. Using uri's? I see that there is a way to use the uri. However, the documentation with this also only mentions Android and ios. I tried it anyway, both "ms-sfb" and "skype". Both of them popup a message stating that I need to find the app in the store, even though it is installed.

Anybody know of the best way, currently, to get skype for business integration into my uwp app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Javascript in your UWP apps, you can easily integrate Skype For Business Functionality using Skype Web SDK. And it's not platform dependent. As javascript is not platform dependant. If you are doing it o n .NET you can use UCMA API.

Comment: I ended up having to use UCMA API to get this done. I hope that soon they will create an API/SDK for UWP but UCMA does get the job done.