# Use UWP app to execute Skype for Business calls

Tags: c#, uwp, integration, skype-for-business, cortana

I am implementing an UWP application that can be used as background application for Cortana Voice Commands.
 The UWP app should connect to Skype For Business 2016 MSO and start a call after the user enters a voice command (eg. "Hey Cortana, call Micheal").

As the application will be a small/sperimental internal project in my company (900+ employees using Skype for Business), I wanted to avoid having to setup anything on our Server hosting Skype. Therefore Skype Web SDK would not be an option for me.
 Differently from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169269/integrate-skype-for-business-in-uwp-app), where it is suggested to use UCMA API, I was wondering whether I can simply use the [Desktop API](https://dev.office.com/skype/sdks#desktop-apis) to trigger Skype calls using the local Skype for Business instance.

However the Desktop API is designed for [Lync 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933180.aspx) and I do not know whether it is the way of proceed to integrate Skype for Business 2016 MSO.

Comment: The Desktop API is designed for desktop app like Windows Forms, WPF, or Silverlight application, it can't be used in UWP. If you do want to use this API, you can try to [convert your desktop app to a UWP app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop) and enhance it with Cortana.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I can live with that, but I also read that Lync 2013 SDK, requires Lync 2013 to be installed on the users machines and this would be a show stop for me. All this "old" dependencies make me wonder whether there is a better way to integrate Skype functionalities (eg. start a call) within a desktop application.